# Users can't visit other users in my ruby application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I looked around a lot and found only one question like the one I am asking, And the information in it did not help me with my issues. What I am having an issue with is my users, I have several users. You're able to navigate to the page that displays every user, each one is clickable. But when ever I'm signed in to a user say Profile(1) and I wanna visit Profile(2) page it just loads Profile(1)'s credentials. Age, Bio, and Picture. Whats my issues here? It may be a simple fix and if so then thank you for the help in advance!

This is the page that list all users index.html.erb,

```
<div class="all_users">
  <div class="container">
    <p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

    <h1>Listing Users</h1>

    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>

          <th colspan="3"></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
        <% @users.each do |user| %>
        <ul class="media-list">
          <li class="media">
            <div class="media-left">
              <%= link_to image_tag user.profile_picture.url(:thumb) %>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="media-body">
              <h4 class="media-heading">Name: <%= link_to user.first_name, dashboard_path %></h4>
              <p>Age: <%= user.age %></p>
              <p><%= user.bio %></p>
           </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
          <tr>
            <td><%= link_to 'Show', user %></td>
            <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_user_path(user) %></td>
            <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', @user, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
          </tr>
        <% end %>
      </tbody>
    </table>

    <br/>

    <%= link_to 'New User', new_user_path %>
    <%= link_to 'Login', login_path %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the profile page for the users show.html.erb,

```
<div class="show">

    <div class="col-md-3">                  
        <div class="thumbnail">


                         <% else %>
                                <%= image_tag @user.profile_picture.url(:medium) %>


                              <div class="caption">
                                <h2><%= @user.name %></h2>
                                <p>Message This User  <i class="fa fa-envelope-o fa-lg">   </i></p>
                                <p>Report This User   <i class="fa fa-exclamation fa-lg">    </i></p>
                                <p>Block this User    <i class="fa fa-user-times fa-lg">   </i></p>                 <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg">Add As Friend</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Follow</a></p>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                                <div class="panel panel-default">
                                    <div class="panel-heading">Bio for <%= @user.first_name %></div>
                                    <p class="bio">
                                        <%= @user.bio %>
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                    </div>

                      <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="panel panel-default">   
                            <%= form_for :post, url: posts_path do |f| %>
                                <div class="panel-heading">
                                    <i class="fa fa-pencil-square"></i> <%= f.label :Status  %> |<br>
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel-body">
                                    <%= f.text_area :body, placeholder: "What's new?" %>
                                </div>
                                <p> 
                                    <%= f.submit %>
                                </p>                        
                            <% end %>
                        </div>
                        <%- @posts.each do |post| %>
                            <div class="panel panel-default">

                                <div class="panel-heading-gray"> <%= image_tag @user.profile_picture.url(:thumb) %> <h5 class="user-name"><%= @user.name %></h5> <h6 class="time-posted"><%= post.created_at.strftime("%B, %d, %Y") %></h6></div>
                                <div class="panel-body"><%= link_to post.body, post %></div>
                                <div class="panel-footer"> 

                                    <%= render post.comments %>
                                    <p class="Like-option">Like ·</p>
                                    <p class="comment-form">Comment</p>  
                                    <p class="view-option">· View</p>
                                    <p class="comment-profile-picture">
                                    <%= image_tag @user.profile_picture.url(:thumb) %>
                                    </p>
                                    <%= @post.comments.count %>
                                    <div id="comments-form">
                                        <%=  render "comments/form", :post => post %>

                                </div>  
                            </div> 
                            </div>
                    <% end %>
                  </div>
```

Here is my users_controller.rb,

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  after_action :signed_in_after_register, only: :create 

  def index
    @users = User.all
    @user = User.find(session[:user_id])
  end

  def dashboard 
    @user = User.find(session[:user_id]) unless session[:user_id] == ""
    redirect_to login_path, notice: "You're not logged in" unless @user 
    @posts = @user.posts.order("created_at DESC").limit(3)
    @comment = Comment.new 
    @post = Post.new 
  end 

  def newsfeed
    @user = User.find(session[:user_id]) unless session[:user_id] == nil
    redirect_to login_path, notice: "You're not logged in" unless @user 
    @posts = @user.posts.order("created_at DESC").limit(3)
  end

  def nav
     @user = User.find(session[:user_id])
  end
  def posts
     @user = User.find(session[:user_id])
     @posts = @user.posts
  end

  def destroy
    @user = User.find(session[:user_id]) unless session[:user_id] == ""
    redirect_to login_path, notice: "You're not logged in" unless @user 
  end

  def welcome
    @user = User.find(session[:user_id]) unless session[:user_id] == ""
    redirect_to login_path, notice: "You're not logged in" unless @user 
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id]) unless session[:user_id] == ""
    redirect_to login_path, notice: "You're not logged in" unless @user 
    @posts = @user.posts.order("created_at DESC").limit(3)
    @comment = Comment.new 
    @post = Post.new 
  end

  def new
    @post = Post.new(params[:post_id])
    @user = User.new
  end

  def edit

  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)

     respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to dashboard_path, notice: 'User was successfully created!' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
   end
  end

  def update

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update(user_params)
         format.html { redirect_to dashboard_path, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @user.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to users_url, notice: 'User was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    def set_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end
    def signed_in_after_register 
      session[:user_id] = @user.id 
    end

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :bio, :password, :password_confirmation, :email, :age, :profile_picture, :post, :body)
    end
end
```

and this is my user model user.rb,

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_secure_password
    validates :first_name, :last_name, :email, presence: true, uniqueness: true 
    validates_inclusion_of :age, in: 10..100
    validates :password, presence: true 
    has_many :posts
    has_attached_file :profile_picture, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }, 
    :default_url => "app/assets/images/missing.png", 
    :path => ":rails_root/public/system/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename" 
    validates_attachment_content_type :profile_picture, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
```

I tried putting in User.find(params[:user_id]) and I get the following error

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in UsersController#show 
Couldn't find User with 'id'=
```

EDIT: Here is my routes file,

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root 'welcome#welcome'

  get 'login' => 'sessions#login', :as => :login 

  get 'dashboard' => 'users#dashboard', :as => :dashboard

  post 'logging/user' => 'sessions#create'  

  get 'logout' => 'sessions#destroy', :as => :logout 

  get 'about' => 'about'

  get 'newsfeed' => 'users#newsfeed'

  resources :users, except: :show
  get 'profile/:id' => 'users#show', as: :profile

  resources  :posts do
    resources :comments
  end

  get 'index' => 'posts#index'

  get 'register' => 'users#new', :as => :register

end
```

Answer (score 1):

Which link are you clicking to view a user's profile?

```
<h4 class="media-heading">Name: <%= link_to user.first_name, dashboard_path %></h4>
```

or:

```
<td><%= link_to 'Show', user %></td>
```

If it's the first one why are you linking to `dashboard_path`? Seems like that should be linking to `user_path(user)` right?

Might also help to show us your routes file.

Comment: I added my routes to my question, Also both links are wrong. And adding user_path(user) leads all to the same error. 
    No route matches [GET] "/users/12"

Comment: You've explicitly disabled the `:show` route for your user resource. But added the profile route. You need to change both of the links in my answer to `profile_path(@user.id)`

Comment: Alright, That works! Still one problem, Its not showing the users page. Still just showing the signed in users page and credentials. Thanks for your help so far man!

Comment: Your first line of the `show` action is trying to find a User by `session[:user_id]`, but you are passing in `params[:id]` via the route. Change that up and you should be good.

Comment: When I change that up I still get that same old error.

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in UsersController#show 
Couldn't find User with 'id'=

Comment: @GenoLagana Probably useful to update your question with your latest code.

Comment: I added the change to my controller by editing it. Any update on what the issue is? I still have the same error.

Comment: @GenoLagana Your show action is still trying to find a user with `params[:user_id]`.  Your route is passing in `params[:id]`.

Comment: I can't figure out how to change that. Any help?

Comment: @GenoLagana Change the controller code to use `:id` not `:user_id`.

Comment: Yeah, Its still not working even after changing that man. it still makes the same error. I must be over looking something, I've been spending weeks on something that should be simple.